# Python Folder Splitter directory path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently using a snippet from GitHub to automate a simple project of moving files within a folder to smaller subfolders. Below is code I've found from GitHub:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# @author: Peter Lamut

import argparse
import os
import shutil

N = 10  # the number of files in seach subfolder folder


def move_files(abs_dirname):
    """Move files into subdirectories."""

    files = [os.path.join(abs_dirname, f) for f in os.listdir(abs_dirname)]

    i = 0
    curr_subdir = None

    for f in files:
        # create new subdir if necessary
        if i % N == 0:
            subdir_name = os.path.join(abs_dirname, '{0:03d}'.format(i / N + 1))
            os.mkdir(subdir_name)
            curr_subdir = subdir_name

        # move file to current dir
        f_base = os.path.basename(f)
        shutil.move(f, os.path.join(subdir_name, f_base))
        i += 1


def parse_args():
    """Parse command line arguments passed to script invocation."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='Split files into multiple subfolders.')

    parser.add_argument('src_dir', help='source directory')

    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    """Module's main entry point (zopectl.command)."""
    args = parse_args()
    src_dir = args.src_dir

    if not os.path.exists(src_dir):
        raise Exception('Directory does not exist ({0}).'.format(src_dir))

    move_files(os.path.abspath(src_dir))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm very new to Python, so this is a very basic question and I'm sure that I'm simply overlooking the answer. Where does the file path go in this snippet to direct Python towards the main folder that will be broken into subfolders?

I've copied the address from Windows file explorer, and I'm not sure where it goes to direct the program accordingly.

Last, does the file path remain in the format like "C:/users/yourNameHere/..."?Will I need to put the address in single quotes or parentheses?

As I've said, I'm sure this is very simply, but I'm new to everything so I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: @Johnnyh101 Sorry , should've been more clear. I have it written as : my_file_path = "C://Users//...". The are no quotes around the variable. However, even with this assignment and calling move_files(my_file_path), I get the error "argument required: src_dir". Even when assigning src_dir = "C://Users//..." at the top of the code, it doesn't work. I've tried calling both move_files(src_dir) and main(src_dir) with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows:
Step 1: In notepad or a similar text editor paste the code you provided and save it as folder_split.py
Step 2: Open Windows File Explorer to the folder location of the files you want split into multiple folders.
Step 3: copy and paste the folder_split.py file into this folder.
Step 4: In the Windows File Explorer filepath window delete the path in the window and type "cmd" and hit ENTER. This will open a terminal with the filepath of the folder you will split.
Step 5: In the terminal, type "python folder_split.py ./" and hit ENTER

FYI: You may also need to alter the code you provided above by replacing '{0:03d}' with '{0:03.0f}' or you may get the error that I got "Unknown format code 'd' for object of type 'float'"